# Why i get "An error occurred when processing your submitted information." after a standard field validaton?

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation, error, pageblocktable

I have 3 inputfields from Account object in a pageblock table:

- personemail
- personbirthdate
- personmobilephone

If i type a misformatted email address (for eg. missing @ sign) or birthdate than i press save button I get a standard error message (Error: Invalid Email Address.) After i correct the email address and press save I get  the following error message:

> Error: pg:whole:pb:added:table:0:col2: An error occurred when
>   processing your submitted information.

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me, why this is happening ?

Controller source:

```
public with sharing class mngtp {

    public List<Account> accList {get;set;}


    public mngtp(){

        accList=[select id,personBirthdate,personEmail,  personmobilephone from account where id=:'001m00000058VhU'];

    }

    public void save(){     
        update acclist;
    }    

}
```

Page code:

```
<apex:page controller="mngtp" id="pg">
<apex:form id="whole">

<apex:pageBlock title="title" id="pb">
  <apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom">   
   <apex:commandButton value="Save"  action="{!save}" rerender="whole" />    
  </apex:pageblockButtons>  

 <apex:Pageblocksection id="added"  columns="1">

    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!acclist}" var="acc" id="table">



          <apex:column headerValue="Email">
            <apex:inputfield id="col1" value="{!acc.personEmail} "/>
          </apex:column>


          <apex:column headerValue="Birthdate">
            <apex:inputField id="col2" value="{!acc.personBirthdate} " />
          </apex:column>


          <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
            <apex:inputField id="col3" value="{!acc.personmobilephone} "/>
          </apex:column>



    </apex:pageblocktable>



  </apex:Pageblocksection>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the extra space in your column values:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Email">
        <apex:inputfield id="col1" value="{!acc.personEmail}"/>
      </apex:column>


      <apex:column headerValue="Birthdate">
        <apex:inputField id="col2" value="{!acc.personBirthdate}" />
      </apex:column>


      <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
        <apex:inputField id="col3" value="{!acc.personmobilephone}"/>
      </apex:column>
```